# rails4 scoped has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations

In my `product_users` joint table there is a role column besides the `product_id` and `user_id`.

I have this association in my product model.

```
has_many :owners, -> { where(product_users: { role: "owner" }) }, 
                     through: :product_users, source: :user
```

All of the products will have only one "owner" and the rest will be "member".
What association should I use to to get the `owner` of the product instead of an `owners` collection. So in the views I wanna use `product.owner`. I couldn't figure out how to use either `has_one` or `belongs_to`.

I could use this instance method, but I guess it would be better to define a fine association somehow.

```
def owner
  owners.first
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to do that, would be to add a column "owner_id" to the product. Then, on the product:

```
belongs_to :owner
```

and on the user something like this

```
has_many :owned_products, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "owner_id"
```

The "class_name" tells the association that you will be looking for a "Product" and the foreign_key, will define what column will be used to compare with users id.

If you don't want to add additional column, then you can name association to "has_many :owner", but that's wrong on so many levels, that you shouldn't do it. So in the case you don't want to add additional column, stick to the method.

```
def owner
    owners.first
end
```